# Specialized cache for Nginx, one chache for all requests

Tags: nginx, cache

I am using Nginx as my main webserver. I need to cache some special data, and I need the data from all requests to be stored in one cache and be retrieved from that cache. In each request, I will search the cache and if I found the data, I will make a response using that data, and if I didn't found, I will ask another server for the data.

Something like a database (and one of my solutions is to use a DBMS)
I want to know if there is a good solution for caching such a data, in a way that it be able to response a lot of simultaneous request, as fast as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find memcached useful, and nginx can talk to it (ngx_http_memcached_module).